# Penalty for Fight in Kart racing rule

Tags: kart-racing

Any body knows in the racing when 2 drivers fighting with each other which penalties we should give them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just used to disqualify them both in that race and send 'em home. There's no need for that sort of behaviour.

Even in F1 you'll see they have taken steps ranging from fines and disqualification for that race through to bans and grid penalties for the next race.